# char to uppercase assignment segmentation fault

Tags: c++, char, segmentation-fault, uppercase

In an effort to learn more about the inner workings of c++ I decided to write my own string class. However I am stuck on the `.toUpper()` and `.toLower()` functions. Here is my code.

```
Text& toUpper(){
        char* c = this->str;
        while(*c != 0, c++){
            if((*c >= 'a') && (*c <= 'z')){
                *c = *c - 32;                    
                std::cout << *c << std::endl;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

I have isolated the line that causes the segmentation fault to `*c = *c - 32` but I can't see why this would be causing a problem. I tried `(char)(*c - 32)` but that didn't work. Also it's not a bounding issue because nothing gets output. Any ideas?

Update: My constructor

```
Text(char* str){
        this->str = str;
        this->updateLength(); // glorified strlen
    }
```

My pointer definition

```
private:
    char* str;
    int len;
```

Comment: Issue is with `c++` in the `while`'s condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `while` loop to this:

```
while(*c != 0){
            if((*c >= 'a') && (*c <= 'z')){
                *c = *c - 32;                    
                std::cout << *c << std::endl;

            }
             c++; // Should be here
        }
```

See these:

1. [Your code](http://www.ideone.com/remZR)
2. [Edited Code](http://www.ideone.com/SowK0).

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator):

*In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type). The comma operator has the lowest precedence of any C operator, and acts as a sequence point.*

Comment: `c++,*c != 0` is incorrect.  Consider what happens when the string is empty (`""`).

Comment: I don't understand. Your code works perfectly when the char is declared like an array but causes a seg-fault when its declared as a pointer. Did I declare my pointer wrong? I'll update my question.

Comment: @Nat:: What is `str` storing?? Is `str` a pointer to a string literal or a character array?? Modifying a string literal is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Acme, that was the problem. Thank you. I forgot to copy the string literal pointer to an array.

Answer (score 5):

```
while(*c != 0, c++)
```

The `while` loop in C++ takes a single expression.  It evaluates that expression each iteration to determine whether to continue.

Here, the `,` is the comma operator, not a separator.  The comma operator evaluates the first part (`*c != 0`), discards the result, then evaluates the second part (`c++`) and yields that as its result.

Since you kept incrementing `c`, the condition was never `false` because `c` never becomes `NULL` (note that as written it isn't testing the value pointed-to, it's testing the pointer itself).

Your loop would be cleaner as a `for` loop:

```
for (; *c != 0; ++c)
```